# Uploading images to database ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to upload an image directly to my database. I am having an issue with an object reference not being set to an instance on an object.

First, I added a property to my model.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...

    public byte[] MainPhoto { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

I used Entity Framework to update my products table and everything is good there.

Then I used this method in my controller to write the bits into the db.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Price,Description,Availability,Category,ApplicationUserID")] Product product, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Products.Add(product);
    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    product.ApplicationUserID = userID;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      {
        ImageFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
        product.MainPhoto = ms.ToArray();
      }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(product);
```

Finally, I just put this input in my HTML template.

```
<label for="ImageFile">Upload Image:</label>
<input name="ImageFile" type="file" />
```

I am getting an exception that reads:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

That is throwing an exception on this line:

```
ImageFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
```

It would seem that it is not recognizing the var ms as an instance of MemoryStream, but I'm not 100% sure. Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Are you sure `ImaeFile` is not null? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548401/how-to-save-image-in-database-using-c-sharp

Comment: System.IO.MemoryStream does not contain a definintino for TyByteArray, and MSDN defines ToArray as "Writes the stream contents to a byte array"

Comment: ImageFile is null.  I set a breakpoint. Where could it be being null?

Comment: @KeonnaE. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15043664/1191903

Comment: Did you set your form enctype to "multipart/form-data" so that it supports file uploads?

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  It was a problem with the form method.